# Testing for volume names using winapi

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a winapi to check whether a name is a volume name, without caring if it exists or not?

```
\\?\Volume{11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555}\
```

Of course, this can be done using the regex `\\\\\?\\Volume{[\da-f]{8}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{12}}\\`, but why do it if there's an api available?

Comment: Is just testing the start of the string for `"\\?\Volume` too error-prone? Enumerating the volumes with `FindFirstVolume` *et al* does not appear to be a great problem either (and you'll get an "exist" test for free).

Comment: Speed isn't an issue so I'm using the regex method for now. Enumerating the volumes work however this test needs to work with volume names which don't exist on the current machine as well.